# In Magento 2.4.4 admin when I select any category or product I get this error

Tags: admin, magento2.4

### Magento 2.4.4
All of a sudden, in admin, when I select any category or product I get this error (below)...
Can you please help me resolve this?
Thank you very much.
Chris

**There has been an error processing your request**
More than one node matching the query: /config/type[@name='banner']/additional_data/item[@name='uploaderConfig']/item, Xml is:

Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Config\ContentType\AdditionalData\Provider\BlockDataUrl
            
        
    

        
        
            
                
                    
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                    
                
            
        
        
            
                Magento\PageBuilder\Model\Config\ContentType\AdditionalData\Provider\Wysiwyg\Config
            
        
    
        
            
                pagebuilder_tabs_mobile_form
            
        
        
            
            
            
        
        
            
        
        
            
                
                    
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                            
                                
                                
                                
                            
                        
                    
                    
                        
                        
                        
                        
                    
                    
                        
                    
                    
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                    
                
                
                    
                        
                            
                        
                    
                
            
        
    
        
            
            
        
        
            
        
        false
        
            
                
                    
                        
                        
                        
                    
                
            
        
    
        
        
            
                
                    
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                        
                    
                    
                        
                        
                        
                        
                    
                
            
        
    
        
            
                pagebuilder_slide_mobile_form

Answer (score 0):

**Source From** : [LINK](https://magefan.com/there-has-been-an-error-processing-your-request)

**What are the most common reasons for "There has been an error processing your request" message to appear?**

```
1. Installation of the new Magento 2 theme or extension.
2. Updating Magento 2 or Magento 2 extension.
3. Changes in the template code.
4. Setting configuration.
5. Overloading of the server memory.
```

So, if any of the above-mentioned points are due you will see the default Magento error message "There has been an error processing your request". After that exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Though you see this message you don't know what error is there to be fixed. In order to fix it, you need to find out the source of the problem first.

**Fix "There has been an error processing your request" issue**

Take the following steps to fix "There has been an error processing your request" issue in Magento 2:

> 1. Connect to your Magento 2 server via SSH or FTP.
> 2. Navigate to the **var/report** folder where all Magento 2 error reports are stored.
> 3. Open a file named the same as the **"Error log record number"**. On the screenshot about it is "dbf06a3ee1921fad851b368c0b...". So you
>    need to open the file var/report/dbf06a3ee1921fad851b368c0b... .
>
> **Note**:  In your case the log report number is different, and can be sorted.
>
> 4. Check the **Log File Content**. It contains the full error message and detailed information about where it happened (error backtrace).

Once you have the information from the log file you have an idea of what is going wrong, where it appears, and what needs to be fixed.

**Pro Tip:** If you are a programmer making development and it could be annoying you to go var/report folder and check it every time the error appears. You can enable the direct error displaying on the screen putting your Magento instance into the developer mode.

Run this command to switch Magento into the developer mode:

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```